# How to upload files in along with text inputs in the same form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I am trying to upload an image along with some text input. (if the user gives)

I have written my form like this

```html
<form action="/user/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Something" name="message" />
    <input type="file" name="img" id="image" accept="image/*" />
    <button type = "submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

On the server-side. I am not able to read the `res.body` i.e I am getting `res.body` as `null`. I was able to manage the file uploaded. But only the text input is the problem.

Can someone help me with this problem?

I am using `express` along with `multer` for the file upload.
Here is my server-side code.

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // destination: "./public/posts/",
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    const imageFileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
    const videoFileTypes = /mp4/;
    let storagePath;

    if (imageFileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname))) {
      storagePath = "./public/posts/";
      return callback(null, storagePath);
    } else if (videoFileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname))) {
      storagePath = "./public/videos/";
      return callback(null, storagePath);
    } else {
      callback("ERROR: Invalid File Type");
      return;
    }
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // FIELD NAME IS THE NAME YOU ASSIGNED TO THE INPUT FIELD IN EJS FILE
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  // limits: {fileSize: 1000000}
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    //CUSTOM FUNCTION TO CHOOSE ONLY IMAGE AND VIDO FILES
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
}).single("img");

const checkFileType = (file, cb) => {
  const imageFileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  const videoFileTypes = /mp4/;
  //CHECK THE EXTENCTION
  const isImageExtenction = imageFileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const isVideoExtenction = videoFileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  //CHECK THE MIME TYPE
  const isImageMimeType = imageFileTypes.test(file.mimetype);
  const isVideoMimeType = videoFileTypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if ((isImageExtenction && isImageMimeType) || (isVideoExtenction && isVideoMimeType)) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    return cb("Invalid file type");
  }
};
//**************************THIS IS THE UPLOAD ROUTE*************
router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.send("file upload failed");
      return;
    } else {
      // console.log(req.file);
      console.log(req.body.name);
      res.send("file uploaded");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Add the server side code also. How you are submitting the form whit a button an input or else? What are you using as server, express?

Comment: Actually you should call req.body.message instead req.body.name i think becouse your input name is “message”

Comment: Np, u’r welcome!

Comment: Please don't reuse questions for new completely different questions and invalidate comments. You can ask a new question instead.

Comment: beside from repetions in your code that could be avoided by reducing the cyclical complexity, should not the route be `./user/upload` and the async middleware `await` for the upload ? it would also be helpful to log the errors (if any) and where in your code you have assessed the issue arises.